# How to place a UIImage in Navigationbar such that its a logo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uinavigationcontroller

[image][image]I would like to place a logo/image in the left side of `NavigationBar`. I try this in codes, but it is not worked properly.

```
UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: logo];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, 40, 40);
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];
```

I try with view to be placed first then place image as UIImageView but alignment is not good. And moreover view appears to be white space while run the code..

Comment: u have used storyboard

Comment: yes am working in storyboard, ios7.

Comment: in place of last line use this code: self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;

Comment: stii not satisfied with answers? then i will answer.

Comment: @Nirav : Post your answer... Even I am in Kuwait working as iOS developer..

Comment: I will do it after office hours.

Comment: Thx for all.. Finally i solved this issue..:-)

Comment: where are you in Kuwait? can we share contact details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the `Bar Button Item` into your `Viewcontroller` on left Side, and insert the image in `Bar item` see the image

[image]

Comment: will u need any modifications

Comment: It worked great.. But it appears as Bar Button items i.e., whole image appears in blue colour.

Comment: in your question is set the image in the left side on the navigation bar, thats y i given it , will u need add the image in  progrmatically

Comment: u need to add with out navigation bar

Comment: it not a problem, u need to convert or use  your image size in 20 x 20

Comment: adjust the tint and the insets to whatever color/size you like

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my last project, you can create a new logo.png which dimension is equal to 500*88 pixels, make you logo in the left side of it. filled with transparent color from the rest of the png.

```
UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoName_500.png"]];
[titleImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 44)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView;
```

hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];
```

Also make sure UIImage is not nil and it does have a valid image.

Comment: Its a little different to your code. I did look. Did you check UIImage is not nil?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is

```
1. Hide Navigation Bar
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

2. Use image of size 640 x 88 & 320 x 44
   UIImage *navigationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationImage.png"];

3. Use this image in Imageview at frame CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)
   UIImageView *navImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
   navImageView.image = navigationImage;
   [self.view addSubview:navImageView];
```

Comment: I use Navigation Controller and need to display the Navigationbar which is having bg image over that i need to place my logo on left side.

Comment: I can't upload snapshots.

Comment: @yazh : can you post code how you have the background image for navigation bar? I would say post your sample code on dropbox...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with image rendering mode. Can you try the below code

```
    UIImage *logo = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:logo style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

You can even try with your current code by setting the `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIView *titleImageView;


- (UIView *)titleImageView {
if (!_titleImageView) {
     CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    _titleImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44)];
    [self.titleLabelView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImg"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    CGRect imageViewRect = imgView.frame;
    /*
    //adjust image position if you need
    imageViewRect.x = 10;
    imageViewRect.y = 3;
    imageView.frame = imageViewRect;
    */
    [_titleLabelView addSubview:imgView];
 }
return _titleLabelView;
}


self.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleLabelView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *logoItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *logoItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem target:self action:nil];

NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[logoItem1, logoItem2];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and got the below solution,

```
func addIconToNavigationBar(){
    let logoContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "FlashScreenTitle")
    imageView.image = image
    logoContainer.addSubview(imageView)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoContainer)
}
```

In the above solution, I have Created a UIView and added ImageView inside that View. Then Created custom BarButtonItem, with my UIView and assigned it to the leftBarButtonItem.

**Remember to call *addIconToNavigationBar()* in *viewDidLoad()* method**